# Compare rows then take rows out if neccessary

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have an example dataframe looking like below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Area' : ['1', '2', '3', '4','5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
                    'Distance' : ['19626207', '20174412', '20175112', '19396352',
                    '19391124', '19851396', '19221462', '20195112',  '21127633', '19989793'],
                  })

  Area  Distance
0    1  19626207
1    2  20174412
2    3  20175112
3    4  19396352  # smaller, take out
4    5  19391124  #
5    6  19851396  #
6    7  19221462  #
7    8  20195112
8    9  21127633  
9   10  19989793  #
```

The 'Distance' column needs to be ordered by ascending.

But the order of dataframe is fixed (Order of 'Area' is not changable),

which means, if rows are smaller than previous rows, then 
the rows need to be taken out. For example, here is the result I'd like to see.

```
  Area  Distance
    1   19626207
    2   20174412
    3   20175112
    8   20195112
    9   21127633
```

I know I can try something like `for i in range(0, len(index), 1)`...

But is there esaier way to achieve the goal using pandas?

Any hints please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE2:** here is [ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2285236/ayhan)'s solution which will work **properly**:

```
In [135]: df[df.Distance.astype("int64")>=df.Distance.astype("int64").cummax()]
Out[135]:
  Area  Distance
0    1  19626207
1    2  20174412
2    3  20174412
7    8  20195112
8    9  21127633
```

**UPDATE:**

the following solution will **NOT** always work properly, because it will remove **ALL** duplicates. So if you will have duplicated values in your original DF they will disappear.

Here is an example:

```
In [122]: df
Out[122]:
  Area  Distance
0    1  19626207
1    2  20174412  # duplicates
2    3  20174412  # they should BOTH be in the result set
3    4  19396352
4    5  19391124
5    6  19851396
6    7  19221462
7    8  20195112
8    9  21127633
9   10  19989793

In [123]: df.loc[df.Distance.cummax().drop_duplicates().index]
Out[123]:
  Area  Distance
0    1  19626207
1    2  20174412  # one duplicate has been dropped
7    8  20195112
8    9  21127633
```

PS I'll try to find a working solution

**OLD answer:**

i'm not sure whether it's the most efficient method, but it works:

```
In [94]: df.loc[df.Distance.cummax().drop_duplicates().index]
Out[94]:
  Area  Distance
0    1  19626207
1    2  20174412
2    3  20175112
7    8  20195112
8    9  21127633
```

Explanation:

```
In [98]: df.Distance.cummax()
Out[98]:
0    19626207
1    20174412
2    20175112
3    20175112
4    20175112
5    20175112
6    20175112
7    20195112
8    21127633
9    21127633
Name: Distance, dtype: object
```

Comment: I think you can check if current row is greater than the cummax. `df[df.Distance.astype("int64")>=df.Distance.astype("int64").cummax()]`

Comment: @ayhan, that's it!!! Please post it as an answer - it's your solution and it's better than mine.

Comment: I think the key idea was `cummax` - which you came up with, and the duplicates were a minor detail so I think it would be better if you edit your answer. :)